# Safari View Controller uses wrong status bar color

Tags: ios, colors, uinavigationbar, statusbar, sfsafariviewcontroller

My app uses a dark navigation bar color. Therefore I set the status bar color to white (so it has a nice contrast).

[image: red navigation bar with white status bar]

I did this by setting the **barStyle** to black (to make the status bar white) and also setting the **barTint** to my dark red color. Works perfectly.

I present a `SafariViewController` like this:

```
func openWebsite(urlString: String) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: url)
        svc.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

However the status bar of the presented `SafariViewController` still is white. This is a problem because the `SVC` navigation bar has the default white transparent iOS default style. So the status bar is basically invisible.

[image: safari view controller with white status bar color]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by wrapping SFSafariViewController with subclassed UINavigationController.

**BlackStatusBarNavigationController.h**

```
@interface BlackStatusBarNavigationController : UINavigationController
@end
```

**BlackStatusBarNavigationController.h**

```
@interface BlackStatusBarNavigationController ()

@end

@implementation BlackStatusBarNavigationController

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}

@end
```

**Use like this:**

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[BlackStatusBarNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: The best answer & easy I found so far, while still supporting the approved preferredStatusBarStyle method!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can override preferredStatusBarStyle in your viewControllers and return the one you want

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .Default
}
```

or you can set it manually with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.None)
```

how ever for setting it through sharedApplicaion you will need to add this in to your plist
"View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know all this. **Setting the status bar style for my own view controller works perfectly fine**. However I do not know how to make `Safari View Controller` us the correct status bar style. This is an Apple class and not under my direct control.

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent]; doesn't work for you ? adding it before the call?

Comment: Setting `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default` right before calling the SVC does not change anything. This is because I use `View Controller based status bar color` set to `YES`, because my app requires that. I also can not override `preferredStatusBarStyle` for the `Safari View Controller` as it is not my class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set background color of status bar for iOS 13+, you can try to set it force like this.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class CustomSFSafariViewController: SFSafariViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .purple
        }

        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}


extension UIApplication {
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        let tag = 3848245
        
        let keyWindow = connectedScenes
            .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
            .compactMap({$0})
            .first?.windows.first
        
        if let statusBar = keyWindow?.viewWithTag(tag) {
            return statusBar
        } else {
            let height = keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? .zero
            let statusBarView = UIView(frame: height)
            statusBarView.tag = tag
            statusBarView.layer.zPosition = 999999
            
            keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBarView)
            return statusBarView
        }
    }
}
```

There are few useful properties for customization of SFSafariViewController which you can use:

- preferredControlTintColor (color of toolbar items)
- preferredBarTintColor (color of toolbar)

P.S. don't forget to use `CustomSFSafariViewController` instead of `SFSafariViewController`. You can do it like this.

```
let safariViewController = CustomSFSafariViewController(url: url)
```